# Symfony2 - Loading class

Tags: php, symfony

I am having a problem loading a class. It was suggested to use Autoloader but I do not think this is necessary in my case because the class I need is in the same Bundle as the class that needs it.  I dont fully understand the autoloader anyways.

So I have a class

```
<?php

    namespace Nick\AlertBundle\Service;

    class ApiService
    {
        public function AddFlightsAction($alert){
            parseResponseData();
        }

        public function parseResponseData()
        {
            var_dump("Test");
        }
    }
```

So its a basic class, nothing special (I have removed a lot of the functions to cut down on the code).  This is the class I need to use.

Now, I have a listener.

```
<?php

namespace Nick\AlertBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlert;
use Nick\AlertBundle\Service\ApiService;

class AvailabilityAlertListener
{

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        if ($entity instanceof AvailabilityAlert) {
            $uapi = new ApiService();
            $uapi->AddFlightsAction($entity);
        }
    }

}
```

If I remove what is in addFlightsAction and do a var_dump instead, this works.  If I keep it how it is (addFlightsAction calling another function with a var_dump) then I get the error

> Attempted to call function parseResponseData from namespace
>   Nick\AlertBundle\Service (500 Internal Server Error)

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Check your `Apache` or if you're using`NGINX` PHP logs. That should tell you what the `500 Internal Server Error` is. Then you can either fix it yourself or post what the error really is so we can help you better.

Comment: Plus, isn't it `$this->parseResponseData()`?

Comment: normally you must not create an instance of your Service, you should configure it within your config and then just call it. If you need it in your listener then you need to inject it over the listener config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a problem of loading.

Change

```
public function AddFlightsAction($alert){
    parseResponseData();
}
```

To

```
public function AddFlightsAction($alert){
    $this->parseResponseData();
}
```